# How do I detect the EOF parser error from within the code?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, eof

The Code is for a GUI Calculator. How do I detect the EOF parsing error from within my code?

Code:

```
def btnEqualsInput():
    global operator
    if operator!='':
        sumup = str(eval(operator))
        text_Input.set(sumup)
        operator =""
```

Output when I click '=' with 3* in textbox

```
    sumup = str(eval(operator))
  File "<string>", line 1
    3*
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I want to  display "Error!" in the calculator display whenever user presses Equals on wrong syntax in the textbox.

Comment: I suggest that you use a third party evaluator insteal of `eval` because of security issues. `simpleeval` is good.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm just starting out with python, so it's okay for now. I'll definitely look up simpleeval and learn more about the security issues. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch the exception:

```
def btnEqualsInput():
    global operator
    if operator!='':
        try:
            sumup = str(eval(operator))
            text_Input.set(sumup)
            operator =""
        except SyntaxError as e:
            print("Error!",str(e)) #e contains the type of message, for example  unexpected EOF while parsing
```

You can parse the error string as well if you want to do something specific (for EOF for example, `"EOF" in str(e)` will be true)

Answer (score 0):

You want to catch the parser exception:

```
try:
    sumup = str(eval(operator))
except SyntaxError as e:
    print('Error!', e)
```